realistic sampling - where am I wrong?
I’m given a signal $x(t)$, it's convolved with $h(t)$ and sampled at rate T=1. The result is called $\tilde{x}[n]$.

For $$h(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & -0.5<t\le 0.5 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases},$$ find $\tilde{X}^f(\theta)$ as an expression of $X^f(\theta)$.

My attempt
I noticed that I can write for a sampled signal
$$\tilde{X}^f(\theta) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{X}^F\left(\omega = \frac{(\theta - 2\pi k)}{T}\right).$$
All that I had left to do was simplify using the convolution to multiplication relation and this identity:
$$\begin{cases} k & |t|<t_0 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases} \to 2kt_0 \text{sinc}(\omega t_0),$$
I substituted $\tilde{X}^F(\omega)$ into the expression.
Results
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X^F(\theta - 2\pi k)\operatorname*{sinc}(0.5(\theta-2\pi k))$$
whereas what they got:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X^F(\theta - 2\pi k)\operatorname*{sinc}\left(\frac{\theta-2\pi k}{2\pi}\right)$$
I'm losing my mind over the $\pi$ in the denominator, why is it there?

I have no idea what this notation means.  What is "$X^f(\theta)$"?  What is $\theta$?  Is $X(\cdot)$ being raised to the $f$ power?  Why not just use standard electrical engineering notation?

this is the notation I was taught for DTFT, $$X^f(\theta) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}x[n] e^{-j\theta n}$$

It is hard to follow what you did as your nomenclature is inconsistent and you didn't explicitly define any of it.
I believe the bit you got wrong was the Fourier transform of $h\left[t\right]$, with the correct expression for the more general case of a rectangular pulse of height $k$ centred on $t=0$ with width $t_0$ being:
$$\frac{k}{t_0}{\rm sinc}\left[\frac{\omega}{2\pi t_0}\right]$$
Where $\omega$ is the frequency (radians per unit time).
Here is a full solution assuming that $X^f$ is the Fourier transform of the signal prior to convolution, $\bar X^f$ is the final discrete time Fourier transform, and $\theta$ is the frequency (radians per unit time):
Firstly, the Fourier transform of $h(t)$ is:
$$H\left[f\right]={\rm sinc}\left[f\right]$$
Where $f$ is the frequency (cycles per unit time).
Secondly, using the Poisson summation formula and that convolution in the time domain is multiplication in the transform domain:
$$\bar X^f\left[2\pi f\right]=\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}X^f\left[2\pi\left(f-\frac{k}{T}\right)\right]{\rm sinc}\left[f-\frac{k}{T}\right]\\
=\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}X^f\left[2\pi\left(f-k\right)\right]{\rm sinc}\left[f-k\right]$$
Where I have used that the sampling interval, $T$, is equal to $1$, and $\theta=2\pi f$.
Finally, rewriting in terms of $\theta$:
$$\bar X^f\left[\theta\right]=\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}X^f\left[\theta-2\pi k\right]{\rm sinc}\left[\frac{\theta}{2\pi}-k\right]\\
=\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}X^f\left[\theta-2\pi k\right]{\rm sinc}\left[\frac{\theta-2\pi k}{2\pi}\right]$$
This matches the correct expression that you were given.
